# Implementing a model with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to implement one model with dynamic columns.

My model:

```
public partial class AccountViewModel : DbContext
{
    public ACCOUNT Accountdt { get; set; }
}
```

My controller code returning index.cshtml:

```
// To display grid in Kendo UI
public ActionResult Accounts_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    Json(GetAccounts().ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));
}

//To extract data from linq
private IEnumerable<Object> GetAccounts()
{
    var database = new Entities();
    var load = database.ACCOUNTs.AsQueryable();
    AccountViewModel avm = new AccountViewModel();
    return load.Select(account => avm.Accountdt);
}
```

I am not able to see dataset in the result datagrid. Early it is working fine when columns are declare in the model.

Here is my code that's working fine:

```
public partial class AccountViewModel : DbContext
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

// To display grid in Kendo UI
public ActionResult Accounts_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    Json(GetAccounts().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}

private IEnumerable<Object> GetAccounts()
{
    var database = new Entities();
    var load = database.ACCOUNTs.AsQueryable();

    return load.Select(account => AccountViewModel {
        id = account.id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following code,

```
return load.Select(account => avm.Accountdt);
```

as follows,

```
return load.Select(account => new AccountViewModel {
    Accountdt = account
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already try this code but...It does not works.Run time error occur. in
  Json(GetAccounts(SearchPar1).ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));
-----------------------
error message is Not Supported Exception Occur

Comment: `Json(GetAccounts(SearchPar1).ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));`
Not Supported Exception Occur in Run time

Comment: **what is this SearchPar1 standsfor??? – Abhilash Ravindran C K 6 mins ago**
it does not matter..(to search query with linq) .it is just variable does not use.